# What is a word for 'answered correctly'?

Tags: single-word-requests

I *answered-correctly* 4, 5, 6, and 7, but missed questions 1, 2, and 3.

**What is a word for *answered-correctly*?**

I have normally heard *got* used in this context, but I am looking for a word that suggests what is being referred to is a question whereas *got* is more general and does not suggest that. The closest to this I've come up with so far are *solve*, *unravel*, and *unriddle*.

Comment: I don't know what you've got against "answered correctly". But you definitely don't want a hyphen there, and it would be more natural to put the object before the adverb *(I answered 4, 5, 6, and 7 correctly)*.

Comment: You can also say "I correctly answered 4, 5, 6, and 7, but missed ..." That inversion is the normal usage in reference to longer lists. For shorter lists and single items you can split the verb and adverb as @FumbleFingers has done above.

Comment: You *got* 4, 5, 6 and 7, but *missed* 1, 2 and 3.

Comment: **Got** suggests that in context. I got (questions)  4, 5, 6 and 7 is colloquial in American English. You can  specify *questions* if it makes you feel better, but context should make that clear anyway. How'd you do on the test? I *got* a 90. I *got* all the questions right except for one.

Comment: [Related](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2160).

Answer (score 0):

**Nailed** – [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/nail)

> *tr. v.*
> 5. *Slang*
>
> b. To perform successfully or have noteworthy success in: *nailed the dive*; *nailed the exam*.

I *nailed* 4, 5, 6, and 7, but missed questions 1, 2, and 3.

Comment: Nailed means "did perfectly."  The teacher might disagree, but on a yes/no basis, accepted the answer and awarded the point.

Comment: But agc has already offered this.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider ***cracked***.

ODO:

> **[crack](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/crack)**
>   *VERB*
>   **3** *informal* [with object]
>   Find a solution to; decipher or interpret.
>
> ‘We've now discovered another challenge that may be harder to crack.’

Comment: Only if the question was enigmatic.