# Is there another word for a "Correct Prediction" or "Correct Answer"?

Tags: single-word-requests

This word probably doesn't exist, at least I can't think of anything that would possibly fit,

I'm making a leaderboard for a little game where I'm having my players guess (or potentially knowingly choose) answers

It'd look like:

[image]
or
[image]

But I don't like having 2 words in the header there, and I also want to be a little fun.

---

For example, in this question:
[What is a word for 'answered correctly'?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/415225/what-is-a-word-for-answered-correctly)

there was an answer: **"Nailed"**

so maybe **"Nails"** would work, and would be funny, but it may be a little too cryptic

---

I've tried looking at synonyms for "Predictions", but no word also implies correctness

I've tried looking at synonyms for "Correct", but couldn't find anything that also covers predictions/answers

Comment: Single word requests should be accompanied by a textual context. Requests for words for headings are considered off-topic - a simple tick or cross would suffice, but that wouldn’t really be a use of the English language.

Comment: (The right) **guess**. You guessed it right, ha! Also fun could be "**Got** it right."

Comment: Why not just "Score", on the assumption that the players know that they're just getting points for each correct answer.

Comment: Sorry, @Lawrence, I'm new to this stackexchange, so I specifically combed through the tag instructions (https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info) and made sure that I was creating the best question I could.

Comment: @Barmar, I like that simplicity, I think I was trying to be too funny in my head, I'm going to go with "Score"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a single word for *correct answers*, you can use [**accuracy**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/accuracy):

> [Merriam-Webster]
>   noun
>   **1** : freedom from mistake or error : CORRECTNESS
>   // checked the novel for historical *accuracy*

Since it's countable, you can use the plural in your chart:

> ```
> Player     Accuracies
> Joe         7
> Jane       10
> Bob         3
> ```

The use of the word is a little unusual in this context; nonetheless, it's still . . . accurate. (And it might meet your requirement of wanting it to be "a little fun.")

Comment: It feels odd to pluralise 'accuracies' but not 'player'. I prefer both as singular.

Comment: @marcellothearcane I think that Jason is suggesting that each row in the table has only one _name_ but that the number in the _accuracies_ column is a count of the number of accurate answers that the named person has given. This would be similar to heading a column which held the number of offspring for each named person _children_. You would not head that column _child_.

Comment: @marcellothearcane Yes, the first column contains singular entries (just one person), while the second column contains a count that involves plural numbers. However, you could interpret the second column as a kind of single *score* if you wished. The interpretation is up to you.

Answer (score 1):

If you are open to metaphors, consider ***bullseye***:

> **1.2** Used to refer to something that achieves exactly the intended effect.
>   *‘the silence told him he'd scored a **bullseye**’*
>   <sub>[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/bullseye)</sub>